# How to have different build options for two programs in the same autotools project

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf

I have a simple autotools project with two programs: `one` and `two`.

Only one of the program depends on a library (`math` in this example), and I
would like that the other program not to be linked with this library.

Here are my files:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([test], [0.1], [somebody@example.com])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [log])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = one two
one_SOURCES = one.c
two_SOURCES = two.c
```

**one.c** (headers removed)

```
int main(void)
{
    /* do depend on lib math*/
    printf("log[15] = %f\n", log(15));
    return 0;
}
```

**two.c** (headers removed)

```
int main(void)
{
    /* do NOT depend on lib math*/
    printf("15 = %d\n", 15);
    return 0;
}
```

When I build this

```
autoreconf --install
./configure
make
```

The programs are well build :

```
# compilation 
gcc .... -c -o one.o one.c
# link
gcc .... -o one one.o -lm
# compilation 
gcc .... -c -o two.o two.c
# link THE PROBLEM IS HERE, I don't want `-lm` to be added here
gcc .... -o two two.o -lm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only one of the program depends on a library (math in this example),
>   and I would like that the other program not to be linked with this
>   library.

It takes some care to build programs with different options in the same Autotools project.  The usual approach is to create separate output variables for those bits that are not common to all projects, and use them in your `Makefile.am` to define appropriate per-target build variables.

In your example, it is the link options specifying the math library that are target-specific, so you need to capture them in their own variable.  The `AC_CHECK_LIB` and `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` macros both prepend the appropriate library link option to the `LIBS` output variable, which is one of the sources from which Automake draws global link options, so if you use these, you need to also do something to avoid the math library option from remaining in `LIBS`.  Alternatively, you could devise some other mechanism for testing the math library options.

One good trick would be to save the value of `LIBS` before running `AC_CHECK_LIB`, extract the math library options, if any, afterward, and then restore the original value of `LIBS`.  This is a relatively common Autoconf idiom.  For example,

```
LIBS_save=$LIBS

AC_CHECK_LIB([m], [log])

LIBM_LDFLAGS=${LIBS%${LIBS_save}}
AC_SUBST([LIBM_LDFLAGS])

LIBS=$LIBS_save
```

Your `Makefile.am` might then look like so:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = one two

one_SOURCES = one.c
one_LDADD = $(LIBM_LDFLAGS)

two_SOURCES = two.c
```